# Postman .post request stalls, will not process. Why is this happening?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

Here is my code--------

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require("gravatar");

// Load User model
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route   GET api/users/test
// @desc    Tests users route
// @access  Public
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

// @route   GET api/users/register
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exists" });
    } else {
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", // Size
        r: "pg", // Rating
        d: "mm" // Default
      });

      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I attempt a postman test for the .post(/register ... ) route it stalls loading for some minutes before giving me the error of --

"Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/api/users/register.
Why this might have happened:

The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly

Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy

Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General"

---

Tweaking the suggested options did nothing and I'm lead to think neither of these things are the cause,  as I am able to successfully process the .get(/test) route.

**point of note,  I add the key:values in the body of the postman request for name, email and password.  The avatar is generated from the email.

This is the route I use(post) ---  http://localhost:5000/api/users/register

and for reference this is the working route (get)
---  http://localhost:5000/api/users/test

Any help would be great!

Comment: I guess http://localhost:5000/api/users/register will work when you use it as a GET request. Maybe you can try it.

Comment: In a nutshell. `if (user) { // sends res json } else { // not sending response :( ` You don't actually return anything after you go off to create the user ( in fact, you're not even creating the user at this point ). But you need "something". Otherwise your client just hangs there like you are seeing until you eventually get the error on timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to register a user and save it mongoDB and return the response.
What you are doing wrong is you are not responding the data back to user. Also you are not saving anything in the whole API call..

Here's how you can do it.

```
router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exists" });
    } else {
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", // Size
        r: "pg", // Rating
        d: "mm" // Default
      });

      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        avatar,
        password: req.body.password
      });
      newUser.save()
         .then(user => {
              res.status(201).json(user); // 201 is HTTP Code for "Created"
         });
         .catch(next); // we usually handle error in a common middleware, which is why, I am calling "next" here with error as 1st argument.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This helped me out, thank you.  I had to change a few things because I added bcrypt to hash the password.. but the .save() function is what I was missing.  

Also thanks for the status code!

Comment: Glad I was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no return statement in the else block. Try as following... It should work

```
// @route   GET api/users/register
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exists" });
    } else {
    const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
      s: "200", // Size
      r: "pg", // Rating
      d: "mm" // Default
    });

    return res.status(200).json(new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      avatar,
      password: req.body.password
     }));
    }
  });
});
```